# Save Canvas and Pop-up in new HTML window

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

My html 5 canvas is being saved to a server via php. It also pops up in a new window that is not html. The new window only contains the png image. I would like this new popup window to be able to share to social media. I know about auth2.0 and setting that up. What I don't know is how to get my png created from the saved canvas to popup on a new html page so I can add my social media tools. I am pretty sure it would be an edit to this line, window.open(testCanvas.toDataURL("images/png"));.

```
function saveImage() {
cursor.visible = false; stage.update();
var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(testCanvas.toDataURL("images/png"));
var xmlHttpReq = false;       
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
cursor.visible = true; stage.update();
}

else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
ajax.open('POST', 'testSave.php', false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log(ajax.responseText);
}
ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New example without server side (using localStorage)

**On the first page:**

```
<input type="file" id="upfile" />
<script>
    $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

    $('upfile').onchange = function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var f = files[i];
            if (! f.type.match('image.*'))
                continue;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(filecontent) {
                return function(ev) {
                    var b64data = ev.target.result;
                    localStorage.setItem('img', b64data);
                    window.open('popup.html', 'popup', 'width=600,height=400');
                };
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    };
</script>
```

**In the popup page:**

```
<img src="" id="thepicture" />

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('thepicture').src = localStorage.getItem('img');
};
</script>
```

**[Check the working demo here](http://cumfortitudine.com/html5/image-to-popup/)**

Comment: That does not specify an html page to open in that I can add tools to. It also makes the save function not work.

Comment: Paul Rad could you explain the destination a little bit more?

Comment: Sure dude ;) I comment ;)

Comment: I am still having trouble with this. When I plug in our first line the save functin stops working. In the destination I would like it to open in a html page I have already built with social plugins installed.

Comment: i will create a working demo after, i'm currently busy ;) stay tuned.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I am having a hard time telling where the saving of the file ends and the popup code begins. I am not trying to upload and save. I am saving a canvas in HTML5 that has been draw on. I would like the canvas to save as an image and pop up in a new html window. I know the basics of javascript. Been studying it for about two months now.

Comment: Hey Paul, how do I make this work for a "save button" not an "upload button" here is my button code.

    <button onclick="saveImage();" id="saveIt">Save and Post to Social Media</button>